# Minhag - for each of the tribes

Tags: minhag

I heard that there was a "minhag" (custom/practie) for each of the twelve tribes.

Does anyone have a source for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [מגן אברהם ריש סימן סח](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.68.1) says the following:

האר"י ז"ל לא היה אומר פיוטים ופזמונים אלא מה שסדרו הראשונים כגון הקלירי שנתקנו ע"ד האמת, אמנם המנהגים שנהגו בשרשי התפלה אין לשנות ממנהג מקומו כי י"ב שערים בשמים נגד י"ב שבטים וכל שבט יש לו שער ומנהג לבד מה שנזכר בגמרא שוה לכל (הכוונות)

He quotes from the Arizal that each tribe had it's own customs.

Comment: +1 I was thinking of this. But in reality the Shaar Hakavanos actually quoted the Arizal saying this about nuschaos, and that is why the Arizal told his Ashkenazi followers not to switch to nusach Sefard.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer but I would still like to know what is the source from wich Arizal says this. Is there any example of a custom for one tribe and a different one for another? From TaNaKh, Talmud, etc.

Comment: @Mineder there is no such example and thousands of counterexamples of Levites and Israelites (who are assumed from Judah) having the same customs, not to mention Levites having different customs from each other

Comment: The gemara in sanhedrin 16b does explain that every shevet had it's own beis din, as is also elaborated in horayos from 4b and on. Therefore it is possible that different tribes would receive different rulings, however that is rulings, not customs.